# Read selected text in vim

Tags: bash, vim

I have the following bash script (play.bash):

```
#!/bin/bash
pico2wave -l=en-US -w=/tmp/test.wav "$1"
aplay /tmp/test.wav
rm /tmp/test.wav
```

I would like to use it for reading selected text in the vim editor.
The following does not work

```
:'<,'>w !bash play.bash
```

The command executes, but I'm not hearing it.

I'd like to only hear the text, without leaving the vim window.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using the `!` command in vim, your selection will be piped to your script on standard input, not given as a command line argument.

A simple solution would be to modify your script so it reads from standard input:

```
xargs pico2wave -l=en-US -w=/tmp/test.wav
```

`xargs` reads from standard input, then calls `pico2wave` with the data as command line arguments, removing newlines.

Comment: Now, it doesn't read the whole selection but only the first word from the selection.

Comment: @xralf: Hmm, I suspect that in contrast to what its manpage states, `pico2wave` expects a single argument (containing multiple words). You could try using `xargs -d'\0'`, which will cause `xargs` to consume everything up to `EOF` and put it into a single argument for `pico2wave`. The `\0` character is just a character that will probably not be part of your selection.